# C# - Check file size while writing - Change file in middle

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I am looping through directories and getting the files within
While looping, I am writing the file's fullpath name to a file using a StreamWriter
My problem is that I have to control the size of the file - it cant exceed 60K

How can I accomplish this?

I tried changing the streamwriter in the middle of the loop like this:

```
if (myPaths.Length >= 60000)
{
    outFile = "c:\\tag\\GS_dirData_" + (FileCounter += 1).ToString() + ".txt";
    StreamWriter myStream = new StreamWriter(outFile);
}
```

But I am getting an error warning that I cant do this

Here is my full code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("c:/myDir/");
        string outputFile = "c:\\dirA\\PathsFile.txt";
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(outputFile);

        string doneFile = "c:\\dirA\\ConfirmComplete.txt";
        if (File.Exists(doneFile)) File.Delete(doneFile);

        int ct = 0;

        ct = getAllFiles(di, "*.i", sw, outputFile);

        StreamWriter myDoneFile = new StreamWriter(doneFile);
        myDoneFile.AutoFlush = true;
        myDoneFile.WriteLine("Done");
        myDoneFile.WriteLine("Processed " + ct.ToString() + " files");
        myDoneFile.WriteLine("File Size = "+outputFile.Length.ToString());
    }


    static int getAllFiles(DirectoryInfo dir, string searchPattern, StreamWriter myStream, string outFile) 
    {
        var directories = dir.GetFiles(searchPattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        int counter = 0;
        int FileCounter = 1;
        foreach (var file in directories)
        {
            if (file.FullName.Contains("\\BAK\\")) continue;
            myStream.WriteLine(file.FullName);
            counter += 1;
            FileInfo myPaths = new FileInfo(outFile);
            if (myPaths.Length >= 60000)
            {
                myStream.Close();
                outFile = "c:\\dirA\\GS_dirData_" + (FileCounter += 1).ToString() + ".txt";
                StreamWriter myStream = new StreamWriter(outFile);
            }
        }
        return counter;
    }
}
```

}

Any help would be appreciated
I would gladly accept any enhancement ideas

Thanks
David

Comment: What exactly is the error?

Comment: You are creating a local StreamWriter inside your loop.  I don't think you want to do that.  You are closing the outerstream and then opening a new one but not to the same myStream variable.  You are opening to the local one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your code to this:

```
        if (myPaths.Length >= 60000)
        {
            myStream.Close();
            outFile = "c:\\dirA\\GS_dirData_" + (FileCounter += 1).ToString() + ".txt";
            myStream = new StreamWriter(outFile);
        }
```

You are creating a locally scoped variable inside of the if statement.  You need to set the new StreamWriter to the function scoped myStream.

Comment: Worked Great!! Thanks.

By the way, am I checking the file size the right way?
I.e., by making a new FileInfo variable after each loop?

Is there a better way to do this?